# Creating tags in Stack Overflow

Tags: support, tags, tag-creation

How do I create a tag in Stack Overflow?

Comment: Look at the FAQs. Link is at the bottom of this page.

Answer (score 15):

You add tags simply by writing them in the tag field. If a tag doesn't already exist, it will be created.

You will also need the minimum reputation level of 1500.

Comment: Add the minimum required reputation level and your answer is the only one that really answers the question.

Comment: @Konerak - thanks for the comment. Answer updated.

Comment: And if you don't have the rep you can always leave a comment for higher rep users who might add it if it makes sense.

Comment: Is it a good idea if they are automatically created? Who knows how many I've accidentally created! Perhaps there should be a challenge: "Are you sure you want to create this tag?" It could be a simple typo, for instance.

Comment: @winwaed - not really a problem. Moderators can see newly created tags and clean them up. This happens all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Ravi, you require a reputation of at least 1500 to create new tags.

Comment: Does not answer the question.