# Creating a new tag

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, new-users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating tags in Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57753/creating-tags-in-stack-overflow)

I am new to Stack Overflow. Can anyone tell me how to create a new tag?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18878/how-do-i-correctly-tag-my-questions

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you have the [minimum reputation needed](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/create-tags) to create the tag, simply enter it in the tags box and it will be created if it doesn't exist.

There are [guidelines for creating new tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61307/on-guidelines-to-tagging-and-avoiding-unnecessary-tags/61365#61365) though, so be sure you need to create it.

Answer (score 1):

You need a reputation higher than 1499.

Comment: I remember when you used to be able to create tags with 250 rep.

Comment: Is it really 1500 reputation? Reputation inflation?

Comment: @George 250 was too low, people were constantly creating tags that shouldn't have existed